# Jquery / JavaScript / bootstrap continuous images slide effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

i would like to make an images slide effect as this website :
https://www.hackages.io/

I don't know what is the exact name of the effect and If I can do it wiht Jquery / JavaScript or bootstrap ?

Thanks for helping me :D

Comment: check if this helps! http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Responsive-jQuery-Horizontal-Image-Scroller-Plugin-imageSlider/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are not using any slider plugin or any js for this part.They are using css for this animation.Its a one image only and by using css

```
 animation: collage 60s linear infinite; 
    @keyframe collage
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
        transform: translateZ(0);
    }
    main.faea32ab.css:5
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(-1800px,0,0);
        transform: translate3d(-1800px,0,0);
    }
```

using above css they are achieve this slider.If you want to add slider so try to use crawler.js slider for same effect.

Comment: I try crawler.js slider, it work perfect!  Thanks a lot V.S.